# how to remove last td of html table and add new row?

Tags: jquery

Below code is not working properly... 
   it only works for one time how I perform same output as I want... 
   some body can tell what is problem there and why???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create New Table Row</title>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        var counter = 1;
        jQuery('a.newRec').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            counter++;
             var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="textbox[]' +
                 counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="textbox[]' +
                 counter + '"/></td><td ><a href="#" class="newRec">A New Row</a></td></tr>');
             jQuery('table.rec').append(newRow);
            var par = $(this).parent(); //tr par.remove(); };
            par.remove();

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1px" class="rec">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>
<tr >
    <td><input type="text" name="textbox[]"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="textbox[]"/></td>
    <td ><a href="#" class="newRec">A New Row</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note: I am not 100% certain your duplicate naming of the two inputs per row *and the naming format* is valid for post-back. What server technology are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event is is being bound once *at load time* to only the matching elements that exist at that time.

Instead you need to use a delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor element.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var counter = 1;
    $('table.rec').on('click', 'a.newRec', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
         var newRow = $('<tr><td><input type="text" name="textbox[]' +
             counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="textbox[]' +
             counter + '"/></td><td ><a href="#" class="newRec">A New Row</a></td></tr>');
         $('table.rec').append(newRow);
         var par = $(this).parent(); //tr par.remove(); };
         par.remove();

    });
});
```

**Notes:**

- You are provided with a locally scoped jQuery to the DOM ready handler, so just add `$` as a parameter. You can then use `$` within your function without clashes.
- The delegated event handler is attached to your table and listens for click events bubbled up from its descendants. It *then* applies the jQuery selector. It *then* applies to function to any matching elements *that caused the event*. This means it will work for elements that exist at event time (not just *event registration* time)
- Normal practice is to target a non-changing element close to the changing elements, so I chose your `table` with `class=rec`. The default to use *if nothing else is convenient* is `document`. Do not use `'body'` for delegated events as styling can make it not respond to mouse click.

**Suggestion:**

I always recommend avoiding HTML strung together from strings as that is hard to maintain and is error-prone.

An alternative is to place the template in an invisible element (a dummy script block with unknown `type` is a good option), then use that template to construct any new elements.

e.g. **JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nvL9bvk5/1/

```
<script id="newrow" type="text/template">
   <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="textbox[]{i}"/></td><td><input type="text" name="textbox[]{i}"/>   
       </td><td><a href="#" class="newRec">A New Row</a></td>
   </tr>
</script>
```

Which you can use like this (with a regEx to replace all occurrence of any "placeholders"):

```
var newRow = $('#newrow').html().replace(/{i}/g, counter++);
```

e.g.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var counter = 1;
    $('table.rec').on('click', 'a.newRec', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var newRow = $('#newrow').html().replace(/{i}/g, counter++);
        $('table.rec').append(newRow);
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

This makes the template very easy to read an maintain and avoid a lot of common errors (failing to close elements etc).

Comment: I liked the suggestion part - using template for HTML string.

Comment: @anjibman: I use that on most projects, so that HTML stays in the page where it belongs and is maintainable (not in JS strings). :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.newRec', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
         var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="textbox[]' +
             counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="textbox[]' +
             counter + '"/></td><td ><a href="#" class="newRec">A New Row</a></td></tr>');
         jQuery('table.rec').append(newRow);
        var par = $(this).parent(); //tr par.remove(); };
        par.remove();

    });
});
```

Your code did not work, because you **attach an element dynamically after your DOM is loaded**.
So you have to **bind your event-listener to an existing element** (e.g. the document) which is **a parent of your added element**.

So your event has to be propagated to the dynamically added element trough the [delegated](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)-element.
In my example the selector is passed as a second parameter of the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)-function.

Comment: An explanation of the delegated event handler would be appropriate.

Comment: Technically the event handler is *delegated* to the ancestor. Not the the element added. It means literally that responsibility is passed on to the ancestor for it to handle. I added my own answer and explanation too.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes you're right. Got that one wrong. Corrected it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough...

I'd first update your HTML to make the names of the first row be "textbox[]1" for consistency.

You've got to create a click listener on a parent element to listen for clicks on your anchor tag so that when anchor tags are added you don't have to bind new click handlers for them individually.

Here is a link to a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4pkxx34p/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Bind a click listener for the a.newRec to the containing table
    $('table.rec').on('click', 'a.newRec', function (e) {
        // Avoid any unwanted navigation
        e.preventDefault();
        // Clone your existing row
        var newRow = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
        // Update names of text inputs
        $(newRow).find('input').each(function() {
            $(this).attr({'name': 'textbox[]' + String($('table.rec').find('tr').length)});
        });
        // Remove the last row's last td
        $('table.rec').find('tr:last').find('td:last').remove();
        // Append the cloned row to your table
        $('table.rec').append(newRow);
    });
});
```